# Why I can't make a 'link' on j_spring_security_check page?

Tags: java, html, spring

My form code like that on my web .

```
<form:form name="myform" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post" id="loginForm">
```

I have the problem about my code. I want to make link like:

```
<a href="javascript:go('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/forgot.html');">Forgot Password</a>
```

on my Login page. I use Spring to make this web.
But in another page, it's work. Just only on Login page, it doesn't work.

It's appear on my page. But if I click the link, it doesn't work, just stay on the same page .
Please, someone help me to solve that !

Comment: i want a some clarification on this point ````But in another page, it's work. Just only on Login page, it doesn't work.

It's appear on my page. But if I click the link, it doesn't work, just stay on the same page .  ````.Can you be more specific about the behavior that you are seeing?

Comment: Okay..
On Login page, I use spring security page:
`<form:form name="myform" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post" id="loginForm">`
as a header form..

On another page, i use:
`<form:form modelAttribute="machine" class="form-horizontal" name="myform" method="get">`


I just want add a link on Login page that I can go to another page, so I make this code on Login page:
`<a href="javascript:go('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/forgot.html');">Forgot Password</a> `
But it doesn't work.